# Arranging DIV using bootstrap 4 without using extra DIV

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

Arranging DIV is easy using bootstarp grid system, but some time its not achievable for me,

[image: Here the exapmle]

I think it's not very complex and achieve without using extra DIV or code but my junk brain is not capable of achieve this grid deisgn,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout:-

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-12"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-12"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-6"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-6"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Santnam Thanks a lot, Code is Ok on desktop, but it's not ok on Mobile, I'm modify it a little bit just delete sm when it's declare for mobile, after all thanks a lot for your prompt answer

Answer (score -1):

[This site](http://shoelace.io) may help you to create what you want.

Comment: It's a great online tool for creating grid system, but not help me out